# Which Mathematica files may be deleted to save space

Tags: system, installation

After installation Mathematica 8 for Linux takes more than 3GB in the /usr/local/Wolfram/ directory. I suspect that not all of it is relevant if I want to do some occasional computations. Are there subdirectories which can be deleted safely to save some space?

Comment: I don't know if this is safe, and I'm not going to try it here, but the `SystemFiles/Kernel` directory will have several subdirectories which have a 64-bit and a 32-bit version.  If you are using a 32-bit system, you might try deleting the 64-bit versions.  It should save a few hundred MB.

Comment: If you have the (up-to-date) Java runtime installed separately to *Mathematica*, you could delete the copies of the JRE in `SystemFiles/Java/<$SystemID>`. I did this not so much to save space but because the versions *Mathematica* installs are never updated, and old versions of the JRE have serious security vulnerabilities. (And Java 7 is *much* faster than Java 6, so there might be some performance benefit.) I checked the Java 7 release notes to make sure there weren't any major incompatibilities before doing this and haven't had problems so far, but YMMV.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. You can save a lot of space in the `Documentation` directory by using `Delete All Output` on all the larger ones and by using disk compression.  For example, the v7 documentation Notebook for `ContourPlot` is 27.7MB, but after deleting output it is only 192k, and after NTFS compression only 72k.  Doing this will require evaluating the documentation page before you can see the examples, but it will easily save **500MB** for version 7; probably more in later versions.

   You can modify [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2004/5) as per your needs to programmatically delete all the output cells from the notebooks in the `Documentation` directory.
2. As Oleksandr suggests you can delete the `SystemFiles/Java/<$SystemID>` folder(s), which contain copies of the JVM, if you have Java installed separately, saving about **190MB** of space. (Or, following point #3, about half that.)
3. Initial testing indicates that core functionality is retained after deleting binaries for the other system type (32 or 64 bit) from `SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries`, `SystemFiles\FrontEnd\Binaries` and `SystemFiles\Converters\Binaries` saving about **88MB** for version 7.

Under Windows you can use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to easily visualize the space allocation within a drive or directory tree.  That page recommends [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) for Linux and [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) for OS X.

Comment: It's worth noting that `SystemFiles/Java` also contains some JAR files that might be needed (e.g. for activation of *Mathematica* after installation), so my suggestion isn't to delete this entire directory, but just the JVMs (which are in subdirectories named after the `$SystemID` they correspond to). I've edited accordingly. +1 for the suggestion wrt. the documentation, BTW--seems like both the safest and most effective option here.

Comment: @Oleksandr thanks for the fix; quite important!

Comment: WinDirStat is a nice program, but it's first-time run takes incredibily long. I seem to recall something like half an hour or so on a PC I installed it on last year.

Comment: @Sjoerd you mean for doing all files on the disk?  Or some kind of self-compile?  I cannot recall such an event.

Comment: Yes, all files on a disk. Something like 250 GB of files on a 350 GB disk in a 4 year old PC.

Comment: See also this: http://old.nabble.com/Slow-WinDirStat-on-laptop-td24282114.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I will have a look at removing all the output instead of deleting all the Documentation files. I am on Linux. KDirStat used to be my choice but unfortunately it has not been ported to KDE4:( But I know how to do this anyway so this is not an issue here.

Comment: @Sjoerd So it's unpredictable.  For reference I just did a scan of a 1.5TB drive with 700,000 files in 44,000 directories in 5:22.

Comment: @user429540 for my part you're welcome.  I hope my answer proves effective for you.

Comment: I assume that wasn't the first run? I believe WinDirStat is faster in later runs because it doesn't recalculate sizes of directories that haven't changed (or so).

Comment: @Sjoerd I don't think I've done the full drive before.  I also don't recall that kind of caching between sessions but of course I may be mistaken.

Comment: Can one really delete all output from the documentation notebooks and save the changes? AFAIK, all those notebooks have option `Saveable->False`.

Comment: @murray I know for certain that I have done it, but not for my current installation.  It's quite possible I had to set `Saveable -> True`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Then setting `Saveable -> True` in doc files would seem to be a big deal, not only because of how many files are involved but because each file's internal cache and CacheID would be affected.

Comment: @murray I don't remember everything I did before but I know I had it working to my satisfaction.  I'll try to revisit this is the next day or two and provide additional details.

Comment: I just started using Mathematica yesterday on a Mac. Could you please provide more details on how to Delete All Output in all output cells in Documentation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user2246 I haven't done the documentation trimming in a long time.  I'll try to recreate what I did, and update this answer.  It might be a couple of days.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I posted an answer with some code, but I would imagine whatever you had is probably better than what I came up with. It would be great if you could recreate it and add it here.

Answer (score 14):

Half of it appears to be in ../Documentation , you could delete that and look everything up on the Wolfram site on the web

Answer (score 14):

Since Windows doesn't display directory sizes for me I wrote a tiny utility to let Mathematica display them in a collapsible tree form (code at the bottom).

I opened up some candidates for deletion, but you should try them first by moving the specific directories out of the MMA directory structure. As Image_doctor said, the documentation is a good sized candidate, as well as the 32/64 bit versions of the binaries suggested by Szabolcs. Further candidates can be found in the Links directory (but don't touch the MathLink directory; many of the others are probably safe, but no guarantee).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
directoryTree[startDir_] :=
 Module[{names, dirs, files, sizeFiles, sizeDirs, sons},
  SetDirectory[startDir];
  names = FileNames[];
  dirs = Select[names, (FileType[#] == Directory &)];
  files = Complement[names, dirs];
  sizeFiles = Total[FileByteCount /@ files];
  sons = If[Length[dirs] > 0, directoryTree /@ dirs, {}];
  ResetDirectory[];
  sizeDirs = If[Length[sons] > 0, Total[sons[[All, 2 ;; 3]], 2], 0];
  {startDir, sizeFiles, sizeDirs, sons}
]

dirTreeView[{}] := ""
dirTreeView[dT_] := 
  OpenerView[
    {
     Row[{First[dT], " (", Length[dT[[4]]], ", ", Total@dT[[2 ;; 3]], ")"}], 
     Column[dirTreeView /@ dT[[4]], Frame -> All]
    }
  ]

dirTreeView@directoryTree[$InstallationDirectory]
```

Comment: Also, if the OP cared for it, they could probably make it such that all hyperlinks to `paclet:ref/Foo` are replaced with `http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Foo.html`, so that `Information` (`?`) would take them directly to the page in a browser instead of giving an error (if they deleted the docs). The stored paclets used in `ExampleData` could possibly go too...

Answer (score 11):

In general, you can delete directories that correspond to settings of `$SystemID` other than what you use.  For example, I could delete the contents of

```
SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/MacOSX-x86/
```

since Mathematica on my machine has `"MacOSX-x86-64"` as its `$SystemID`, so it will use the files in

```
SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/MacOSX-x86-64/
```

---

Additionally, as an extreme measure, on OS X `MathKernel` is a universal binary:

```
> file MathKernel 
MathKernel: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
MathKernel (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386
MathKernel (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

and you can use `lipo`(-suction, I presume) from a command line to thin it down:

```
lipo -extract i386 -output MathKernel32 MathKernel
lipo -extract x86_64 -output MathKernel64 MathKernel
```

and then rename the appropriate bitted kernel to `MathKernel`.  On my system, this would save about 70 MB.

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to the other answers, here's a code sample that deletes output from the documentation notebooks. Put this in an `.nb` file, save it, and run it - I've tested using Mathematica 10.4. You will need to ensure the documentation notebooks are writable by the user account under which you're running Mathematica while the script runs.

There is a fairly significant catch: in my tests, this crashes the front end. Repeatedly. Every ~200 files, on average. To help work around this, every 20 files the code prints out the number of files it's processed so far, and then saves itself. That way, when it crashes, you can open up the notebook, look at the last printed output, and adjust the first argument of `stripDocs` to match so you can pick up where you left off. I realize this is far from ideal, but in the absence of any specific code in the other answers, I figured it would be useful.

```
directoryTreeRecursion[startDir_] := Block[
  {names, dirs, files, sizeFiles, sizeDirs, children},
  Sow[startDir, "directory"];
  SetDirectory[startDir];
  names = FileNameJoin[{startDir, #}] & /@ FileNames[];
  dirs = Select[names, (FileType[#] == Directory &)];
  files = Complement[names, dirs];
  Sow[#, "file"] & /@ files;
  children = 
   If[Length[dirs] > 0, directoryTreeRecursion /@ dirs, {}];
  ResetDirectory[];
  ]
directoryTree[startDir_] := Reap[directoryTreeRecursion[startDir]][[2]]

stripOutput[filename_, mode_: "Notebook"] := Block[{},
  Switch[mode,
   "FrontEnd",
   (*advise against using this, it will close the current notebook*)
   FrontEndExecute[{
     FrontEndToken["Open", filename],
     FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"],
     FrontEndToken["Save"],
     FrontEndToken["Close"]
     }],
   "Notebook",
   Block[{nb},
    nb = NotebookOpen[filename, Visible -> False];
    NotebookDelete[Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Output"]];
    NotebookSave[nb];
    NotebookClose[nb];
    ],
   _,
   Message[stripOutput::mode, mode];
   ]
  ]
stripOutput::mode = "`1` is not a valid mode; only \"Kernel\" or \"FrontEnd\" is recognized."; 

doclist = directoryTree@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation"}];
docnblist = Select[doclist[[2]], StringEndsQ[#, ".nb"] &];

timeFormat[seconds_] := Block[
  {h = Floor[seconds/3600], m = Mod[Floor[seconds/60], 60], 
   s = Mod[seconds, 60]},
  TemplateApply[
   If[h > 0, "`1`:`2`:`3`",
    If[m > 0, "`2`:`3`",
     "0:`3`"
     ]
    ],
   {h, If[m < 10, "0" ~~ ToString[m], m], 
    If[s < 10, "0" ~~ ToString[s], s]}
   ]
  ]

stripDocs[min_, max_] := Block[
  {
   numberTemplate = 
    StringTemplate["Currently processing `1` of `2`"],
   timeProgressTemplate = 
    StringTemplate["`1` elapsed, `2` estimated remaining"],
   startTime,
   fn
  },
  startTime = AbsoluteTime[];
  Monitor[
   For[i = min, i <= max, i += 1,
    fn = docnblist[[i]];
    stripOutput[fn];
    If[
     Mod[i, 20] == 0,
     PrintTemporary[i];
     NotebookSave[];
     Pause[1]
     ]
    ],
   Column[{
     ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i], {min, max + 1}, 
      ImageSize -> {500, 20}],
     numberTemplate[i - min + 1, max - min + 1],
     With[{t = AbsoluteTime[] - startTime}, 
      timeProgressTemplate[timeFormat@Ceiling[t], 
       timeFormat@Ceiling[(max + 1 - i)/(i - min + 1) t]]],
     docnblist[[i]]
     }]
   ]
  ]

stripDocs[1, Length[docnblist]]
```

Parts of this code were adapted from [Sjoerd's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6200/79) and, on another question, [Szabolcs' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2004/79), [István's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55100/79), and [bobknight's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55149/79)

Comment: Many thanks! This ran on my linux-x86-64 copy of Mathematica 11.3, crashing only once around file 13000 of 13500 or so. To make the files writable, I ran      `sudo chmod -R 777` on the Documentation directory, afterwards reverting to 755. The directory went from 5.1Gb to 2.0Gb.