# Visualizing directories

Tags: visualization, files-and-directories, trees

How do I plot the content of a directory and all its subdirectories into infinity using `TreeForm`? I've tried using a mix of `FileNames`, `StringSplit` and `GatherBy` but in the end I couldn't find even a promising start.

Comment: Does it have to be TreeForm? Could it be TreePlot?

Comment: Yes, that would work too (I choose TreeForm because I thought formatting the list in that way would not be too hard).

Comment: Take a look at the `makeTree` function in [Leonid's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/447/5) on implementing Tries. By redefining the RHS of the first line in the definition as `makeTree[StringSplit[wrds, "/"]]`, you can get a good structure for the directory tree with `makeTree@FileNames["*", {"*"}, ∞]` (you'll have to clean up the `{{} -> {}}`). While this can't be plugged in a built-in graph function like `Graph` or `TreePlot`, it can be easily converted to a graph using some custom code.

Comment: An alternatieve presentation here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6200/57

Comment: Thx @Hypnotoad your solution worked well. Posted it below. (Thx to everyone else as well!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a relatively straightforward "first version":

```
ellipsizeMax = 8;
ellipsize[str_] := If[StringLength[str] > ellipsizeMax, StringTake[str, ellipsizeMax] <> "\[Ellipsis]", str];

readDir[currentDirectory_, 0] := ellipsize[FileNameTake[currentDirectory]];
readDir[currentDirectory_, level_] := Module[{joinedFiles, perFile},
   SetDirectory[currentDirectory];
   joinedFiles = FileNameJoin[{currentDirectory, #}] & /@ FileNames[];

   perFile[file_] := If[DirectoryQ[file],
     FileNameTake[file] @@ readDir[file, level - 1],
     ellipsize[FileNameTake[file]]];

   perFile /@ joinedFiles
   ];

treeDir[dir_] := TreeForm[dir @@ readDir[dir, 5]];

treeDir["C:/blah/blah"]
```

This has a very poor display capacity if there are more than a certain number of files in a directory level.

It would need a lot of work to make the presentation reasonable in the general case. But this form of tree presentation of a file system also has a *lot* of potential. For example, you could build a graphical navigation system based on this (though not necessarily with `TreeForm`).

Comment: I posted an answer shamefully stealing your code. Hope you don't mind

Comment: @belisarius Absolutely not. Plus, a lot of my answers (such as this one) are more rough sketches than complete answers. I'm more interested in the "conversation," so to speak. :)

Answer (score 12):

The following is a slight modification to @amr's code.

It shows a directory tree using `TreeForm[]`, with a button at each vertex. When the button is pressed, it opens a dialog with the list of the files contained in that directory.

```
ellipsizeMax = 8;
ellipsize[str_] := 
  If[StringLength[str] > ellipsizeMax, 
   StringTake[str, ellipsizeMax] <> "\[Ellipsis]", str];

readDir[currentDirectory_, 0] := ellipsize[FileNameTake[currentDirectory]];
readDir[currentDirectory_, level_] := 
  Module[{joinedFiles, perFile}, SetDirectory[currentDirectory];
   joinedFiles = FileNameJoin[{currentDirectory, #}] & /@ FileNames[];
   perFile[file_] := 
    If[DirectoryQ[file], file @@ readDir[file, level - 1], 
     Sequence @@ {}]; perFile /@ joinedFiles];


treeDir[dir_] := Module[{k}, 
                TreeForm[dir @@ readDir[dir, 5],
                     VertexRenderingFunction -> 
                         (Inset[Button[#2,
                                If[(k = FileNames["*.*", #2]) == {},
                                        CreateDialog["No Files", WindowTitle -> #2],
                                        CreateDialog[k, WindowTitle -> #2]]], #1] &)]]

treeDir["C:\\ff2"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code required to implement Hypnotoad's solution (see comment to the question). I've copied Leonid's code over from its [original thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-a-trie-be-implemented-efficiently/447#447).

The one problem I had with this solution was that `FileNames["*", {"*"}, ∞]` doesn't include empty directories. I replaced it with FileNames["*", Directory[], ∞], which solves that. But Directory[] is an absolute path so all those folders leading up to your current folder will be shown in the graph. I don't know how to solve that, one would have to find a replacement to `{"*"}` which includes directories but at the same time produces relative paths.

```
ClearAll[makeTree];
makeTree[wrds : {__String}] := makeTree[StringSplit[wrds, "/"]];
makeTree[wrds_ /; MemberQ[wrds, {}]] := 
  Prepend[makeTree[DeleteCases[wrds, {}]], {} -> {}];
makeTree[wrds_] := 
 Reap[If[# =!= {}, Sow[Rest[#], First@#]] & /@ 
    wrds, _, #1 -> makeTree[#2] &][[2]]

ClearAll[getSubTree];
getSubTree[word_String, tree_] := 
 Fold[#2 /. #1 &, tree, Characters[word]]

ClearAll[inTreeQ];
inTreeQ[word_String, tree_] := 
 MemberQ[getSubTree[word, tree], {} -> {}]

ClearAll[getWords];
getWords[start_String, tree_] := 
  Module[{wordStack = {}, charStack = {}, words}, 
   words[{} -> {}] := wordStack = {wordStack, StringJoin[charStack]};
   words[sl_ -> ll_List] := Module[{}, charStack = {charStack, sl};
     words /@ ll;
     charStack = First@charStack;];
   words[First@
     Fold[{#2 -> #1} &, getSubTree[start, tree], 
      Reverse@Characters[start]]];
   ClearAll[words];
   Flatten@wordStack];
SetDirectory["~/dirtest"];

TreeForm[
 DeleteCases[
   makeTree@Select[
     FileNames["*", Directory[], \[Infinity]], DirectoryQ
     ], {} -> {}, {0, Infinity}] //. {Rule[a_, {}] :> a, 
   Rule[b_, c_] :> Apply[b, c]},
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Style[Text[#2, #1], 14, 
     Background -> White] &)
 ]
```