# Visualizing directories--a cleaner view of a helpful older post

Tags: visualization, files-and-directories, trees

I am looking to make graphics of a folder hierarchy, and [this old post was very helpful](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17365/visualizing-directories). However, this method gives the whole file path for each node, which makes a complete mess in the directory I want to use it. It must not be too tricky, but I cannot figure out how to get just the last part of the path from each node of the tree structure.

In the abstract, if I have `tree = a[b[c,d,e],g[h]]`, I believe I want some way of performing `F[tree] = F[a][F[b][F[c],F[d],F[e]],F[g][F[h]]]`. I am struggling to implement.

In the concrete, I mildly adapted the code from the linked question above:

```
readDir[currentDirectory_, 0] := FileNameTake[currentDirectory];

readDir[currentDirectory_, level_] := 
Module[{}, SetDirectory[currentDirectory];
joinedFiles = 
FileNameJoin[{currentDirectory, #}] & /@ FileNames[];
unjoinedFiles = FileNames[];

(*do a logical test;
if the thing in a directory is a directory,*)
perFile[file_] := 
If[DirectoryQ[file],(*condition*)
 file @@ readDir[file, level - 1],(*true*)Sequence @@ {}];(*false*)
perFile /@ joinedFiles];

treeDir[dir_] := TreeForm[dir @@ readDir[dir, 11]]

treeDir["/Users/vironevaeh/a"]
```

This yields the nice tree, but with the less-nice filepaths built in:
[image]

Can I either: (1) apply a function to the nested expression that gives me the first graphic, or (2) rewrite the generative code in another way, to give me the following from the directory input:

[image]

Comment: Try e.g.: `treeDir[dir_] := TreeForm[dir @@ (readDir[dir, 11] /. _String :> Unique[])]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on Daniel's comment, here is one way:

```
treeDir[dir_] := TreeForm[
  dir @@ (readDir[dir, 11] /. s_String[] :> s /. name_String :> FileNameTake[name])
  ]
```

Example:

```
treeDir["C:\\\\Program Files\\\\JetBrains\\\\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are two replacement rules added in this example:

`s_String[] :> s` takes care of the `[]` in `filename[]` that appears in the original code.

`name_String :> FileNameTake[name]` selects the last component in the file path as the name.

Comment: If a `Graph[]` is desired: `treeDir[dir_] := ExpressionGraph[dir @@ (readDir[dir, 11] /. s_String[] :> s /. name_String :> FileNameTake[name]), PlotTheme -> "ClassicDiagram", VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center]]`