# Find a notebook I had open recently

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories, save

I worked on a notebook a few weeks ago and now I can't find after looking through the most likely directories. The recent list only has 6 items in it, none of them the notebook in question. Is there a way to find ALL notebooks I have created or opened?

Comment: You may use your OS commands ... find, search, whatever

Comment: Yes, but then the wolfram Force would not be with me.

Comment: @Tyler Durden: Are you sure Edward Norton's character didn't put it somewhere else?

Comment: belisarius is right. Although it is easy to search your hard drive using a simple Mathematica program, it doesn't make sense to write one if your OS already provides tools for it.

Comment: Sometimes I wake up and things are missing.

Comment: That's why coffee was invented.

Comment: Anyway, perhaps [this utility](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6200/57) I wrote provides some inspiration for the task at hand?

Comment: That kind of things usually turn out bad http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102945/

Comment: I have to agree with belisarius and Sjoerd, use the OS search facility. E.g. on Windows 7 you just hit the windows button and type `ext:.nb date:>25/10/2013` to instantly find all notebooks modified after 25th October.

Comment: Don't go beating yourself up over this ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to tell Mathematica to remember, in its File->Open list, long list of files you have opened and not the default of 8.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is from options. Simply change the value from 8 to say 100, and now you will have all those files remembered. I used to have the same problem as you until I found this option.

Comment: Can you force this history display to include the parent folder and not just the filename?

Comment: @Alan good question that I also wanted. No, I am afraid I do not know how. You can ask separate question on this and see if someone have any ideas.

Answer (score 8):

The following function finds a notebook (a .nb file) with a given maximum age (in days) in a given directory or its subdirectories:

```
notebookSearch[dir_String, age_?NumericQ] := 
   Select[
      FileNames["*.nb", {dir}, Infinity], 
      First[DateDifference[FileDate[#], DateList[], "Day"]] <= age &
   ]
```