# Creating a nested menu with OpenerView

Tags: interface

I have a file with the following structure:

```
GAME
{
    version = 0.23.5
    linkURL = 
    Mode = 1
    PARAMETERS
    {
        FLIGHT
        {
            CanQuickSave = True
            CanQuickLoad = True
        }
    }
    SCENARIO
    {
        name = ScenarioDiscoverableObjects
        scene = 7, 8, 5
         = 703987854
        sizeCurve
        {
            key = 0 0 1.5 1.5
            key = 0.3 0.45 0.875 0.875
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to create a nested menu for easy visualization of the file's contents. I've managed to parse the file to the following structure:

```
data = {"GAME", {"version", "0.23.5"}, {"linkURL", ""}, {"Mode", 
  "1"}, {"PARAMETERS", {"FLIGHT", {"CanQuickSave", 
    "True"}, {"CanQuickLoad", "True"}}}, {"SCENARIO", {"name", 
   "ScenarioDiscoverableObjects"}, {"scene", "7, 8, 5"}, {"", 
   "703987854"}, {"sizeCurve", {"key", "0 0 1.5 1.5"}, {"key", 
    "0.3 0.45 0.875 0.875"}}}}
```

I then started to make the menu using [`OpenerView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenerView.html):

```
OpenerView[{First[#], Column[Rest[#]]}] &@data
```

However, I can't manage to apply this function over all levels of `data`.

edit: Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: menu screenshot]

Comment: `Map` has a level specification option. You could set that at Infinity.

Comment: Or use recursion, like [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6200/57)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, this looks promising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/which-mathematica-files-may-be-deleted-to-save-space/6200#6200) provided by @SjoerdC.deVries, here's how I solved it:

```
menu[s_String] := s
menu[l_List] := OpenerView[{First[l], Column[menu /@ Rest[l]]}]
menu[data]
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this fits your needs:

```
f[x : {_, _}] := OpenerView[x]
f[{x_, y_, z__}] := OpenerView[{x, Column[{y, z}]}]
f[x_] := x
MapAll[f, data]
```

> [image]

`Map` scans from top to bottom that's why I've used it not `ReplaceAll` which scans from bottom to top.