# Using Mathematica notebooks with no local back end

Tags: remote-access, installation, storage

My laptop is a Windows 10 Asus netbook with very little (32GB) storage space. I currently use an Ubuntu 18.04 computer for Mathematica, but I would like to be able to use it on my netbook instead. (I do sometimes use X11|SSH to run mathematica on my laptop, but the lag becomes frustrating quickly.)

Is there any way to install the notebook interface and documentation without installing the kernel at all? If not, is there any way to install it and subsequently delete the kernel?

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen someone suggest removing the *kernel* to save space...

Comment: Well I don't really want Mathematica on the laptop at all, I basically want remote desktop with a more responsive front-end.

Comment: The documentation is by far the largest footprint. It would be better to find a way to install Mathematica without the documentation if you are concerned about space.  You can use the online documentation instead.

Comment: How about a RaspberryPi emulator on your laptop with Mathematica for RaspberryPi installed?

Comment: If your concern is saving space, then removing the kernel doesn't help much. Please see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174220/187) to understand that the documentation is by far the largest part of the installation.

Comment: I often fiddle around in the documentation pages while trying to understand a symbol's functionality, so I would rather not use the online docs. However, I could delete the local docs and replace them with a symlink to those on the desktop. Which brings me back to the question: what files can I delete if I'm not planning to ever evaluate anything locally?