# How to select and delete all Output cells?

Tags: front-end

How to select and delete all Output cells in multiple notebooks **programmatically** without needing to (manually) opening them?

How to define a hot key for deleting all Output cells within a notebook from that notebook?

Comment: Maybe some useful information [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2003/134).

Comment: I think this is answered in the answers to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2003/16), as @b.gatessucks points out.

Comment: I assume you know about the delete all output cell option in the Cell menu? If so it should be straightforward to assign a key to this (cf @acl and @b.gatessucks)? But may be you want a non interactive option?

Comment: Actually the linked in the comments thread does not show simplest menu-wise solution.

Comment: Both how to do this programmatically on multiple notebooks, and how to do this from within the notebook using a hot key.  From the referenced threads, it's not clear where to put `KeyEventTranslations.tr`?  Can i put it some where in `$UserBaseDirectory`?

Comment: Yes, you put it in `$UserBaseDirectory`. If  the original is at `$InstallationDirectory/foo/bar/file.tr`, then you mirror the tree and copy it to `$UserBaseDirectory/foo/bar/file.tr`

Comment: by the way, you can hold Alt + click on a cell to select all cells of that type. i use this for deleting error output

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without adressing the hotkey issue (you could add a menu entry, or simply put an appropriate `Button` in your notebook), here is one variety that uses `NotebookDelete` and can be modified to include different `CellStyle`s as well. The first argument *nb* defines which notebook to work on, the second argument *styles* defines the styles of to-be-deleted cells:

```
CleanNotebook[nb_: SelectedNotebook[],styles_: {"Output"}] := 
   (NotebookFind[nb, #, All, CellStyle];
    NotebookDelete[nb];) & /@ styles
```

Together with `NotebookOpen`, `NotebookSave` and `NotebookClose` and related functions you should be able to work on arbitrary notebooks programmatically.

Example:

```
docpath = 
  ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", 
    "System"}, "ExampleData"];

nb = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[docpath, "document.nb"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
CleanNotebook[nb]
```

Take care what other styles you choose, they´ll be gone for good...

**Edit**: You may also use the Option [`Visbible->False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookOpen.html) to supress the opening of a window for this notebook. This seems useful for batch processing (especially if `Dynamic` stuff is involved, because this will probably not trigger if invisible), but takes additional care to save and close programmatically because invisble windows do not show up in the menu bar.

Example:

```
doc = ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", 
    "System", "ExampleData"}, "document.nb"];

bak = ToFileName[$TemporaryDirectory, "document_clean.nb"];

nb = NotebookOpen[doc, Visible -> False];
CleanNotebook[nb];
NotebookSave[nb, bak]
NotebookClose[nb]

NotebookOpen[doc];    
NotebookOpen[bak, Visible -> True];
```

There is still an issue with the `Visible` option being saved in the backup notebook and hiding when reopened (thus re-setting `Visible->True`).

Comment: Is that a typo that the second instance of `SelectedNotebook[]` should be `nb`?

Comment: If i'm applying the function should the first argument be simply the file name (a `_String` expression) or that wrapped with `NotebookOpen`?

Comment: @MonkeyKing: Correct! Fixed...

Comment: @MonkeyKing: If you use `NotebookOpen` it returns a `NotebookObject`. This `NotebookObject` can be used as a handle for subsequent actions. See edit.

Comment: If you use this method on many notebooks, wouldn't it cause many notebooks quickly open on your screen and close?  Is there a way to open them for kernel but not visually to human?

Comment: @MonkeyKing do you just want to hide/minimize the notebooks using the frontend or do you need a sole kernel session without a frontend?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a pure kernel session.  I was just double checking if there's a way (such as an option to `NotebookOpen`) to open the notebooks without having it flash (i.e. quickly open and close in a sec on screen) on screen, if i have thousands of notebooks to process, say.

Comment: Also, asking thousands of notebooks to open and close continuously seems prone to crash FE and/or Mathematica.

Comment: @MonkeyKing re stability: can't say. You'd have to test this. Your question does not mention multi-kilo notebooks. Minimizing and/or working from the kernel should be possible but I'd revommend a new/revised question for that.

Answer (score 7):

This is how you do it through menus, As correctly noted in the comment this is equivalent to the shortcut **ALT+C >> L >> ENTER**.

[image]

Comment: I find the keyboard shortcut **Alt c l Enter** much faster

Comment: @RolfMertig yes, noted in the post, thanks.

Comment: I'm using Alt-C UpArrow Enter, so I really hope that entry will stay the second to last in future versions :-)

Comment: What about in Mac? `Alt`+`c` types in `ç` for me.

Answer (score 5):

**Update December 6th: There is an updated version (plus a bug fix for M9) working on Windows, MacOSX and Linux available and installable by**

```
  Import["http://www.mertig.com/mykeys.m"]
```

On Windows (Mac does not work yet):
Execute the following code in a notebook and restart Mathematica.

Then hitting F4 will delete all Output, Print and Message cells in the selected notebook, while pressing F8 will do so in all open notebooks which are not Wolfram Documentation notebooks. This was more difficult to program than it should be ...

```
$OverWriteUserBaseDirectoryKeyEventTranslations = True;
    mymenuitems="
       (* Delete all Output, Message and Print cells in the selected notebook *)
                 Item[KeyEvent[\"F4\"(*, Modifiers -> {\"Control\",\"Shift\"}*)], 
                 KernelExecute[
                   Module[{nb = SelectedNotebook[]},
                    Scan[Function[c, If[NotebookFind[nb, c, All, CellStyle, AutoScroll -> False] =!= $Failed,
                                    NotebookDelete[nb, AutoScroll -> False]]  
                             ],
                     {\"Message\", \"Output\", \"Print\"}
                    ];
                 SelectionMove[nb,After,Notebook];
              ]
            ], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic ],\n
  (* Delete all Output, Message and Print cells in all open notebooks *)
             Item[KeyEvent[\"F8\"], 
             KernelExecute[
               Module[{nbs = Notebooks[]},
                Quiet[nbs = Select[nbs,  Function[z, Not[StringMatchQ[ Replace[ NotebookFileName[z], $Failed :> \"\"],
                                                                           \"*Wolfram*Documentation*\"]]]]];
                    Do[
                    Scan[Function[c, If[NotebookFind[nb, c, All, CellStyle, AutoScroll -> False] =!= $Failed,
                                    NotebookDelete[nb, AutoScroll -> False]]  
                             ],
                     {\"Message\", \"Output\", \"Print\"}
                    ];
                 SelectionMove[nb,After,Notebook],
                {nb,nbs}]
              ]
            ], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic ],";
Quiet@CreateDirectory@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","TextResources",$OperatingSystem}];
mykeyeventtrans=FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","TextResources",$OperatingSystem,"KeyEventTranslations.tr"}];
If[$OverWriteUserBaseDirectoryKeyEventTranslations===True,
    If[FileExistsQ[mykeyeventtrans],DeleteFile@mykeyeventtrans];
    CopyFile[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","TextResources",$OperatingSystem,"KeyEventTranslations.tr"}],mykeyeventtrans]
];
keytext=Import[mykeyeventtrans,"Text"];
mykeytext=StringReplace[keytext,"EventTranslations[{":>StringJoin["EventTranslations[{\n",mymenuitems,"\n"]];
Export[mykeyeventtrans,mykeytext,"Text"];
```

Comment: How about including Undo option? Instead of `NotebookDelete[..]` use `MathLink\`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd\`SelectionAddCellTags[nb, {"$deleted"}]]` and then just before the last command `SelectionMove[..]` insert this `If[NotebookFind[nb, "$deleted", All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False] =!= $Failed, MathLink\`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd\`SelectionRemoveCellTags[nb, {"$deleted"}]]; FrontEndTokenExecute["Clear"]];`

Answer (score 5):

[Yves Klett's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/how-to-select-and-delete-all-output-cells/13982#13982) is still pretty simple, but I thought I would add an alternative V9 solution using [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cells.html)

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[]; (* change as desired *)
cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> {"Output"}];
CopyToClipboard @ NotebookRead @ cells; (* optional - saves cells for pasting *)
NotebookDelete[cells]
```

Beware: Pasting the cells back into the notebook will replace the current selection.  *It is not an "undo" command.*  It potentially could save an enormous amount of data, which you might not always want.

Here's a modification of Yves Klett's function `CleanNotebook`, with an improvement suggested by @CarlWoll:

```
deleteStyle[nb_: SelectedNotebook[], styles_: {"Output"}] :=
  With[{cells = Flatten[Cells[nb, CellStyle -> styles]]},
    (* CopyToClipboard@NotebookRead@cells; (*optional*) *)
    NotebookDelete[cells]
   ]
```

Again, there's no "undo" for this, so be careful.

Comment: `Cells[nb, CellStyle -> {"Input", "Output"}]` selects both "Input" and "Output" cells, no need to use `Map`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: The advantage of this approach (as compared to [Yves Klett's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13982/280)) is that it won't open collapsed cell groups containing the cells to delete. But for some reason it is much slower and requires more memory (taken by the FrontEnd) even without `CopyToClipboard`. On a Notebook of size 252 Mb the Yves Klett's `CleanNotebook[]` takes 2.5 sec to evaluate and the FrontEnd takes 1.88 Gb of memory ("Private Set" according to Windows Task Manager), but `deleteStyle[]` takes 64.2 sec to evaluate and the FrontEnd takes 2.43 Gb of memory (fresh session).

Comment: (OS Windows 7 x64, *Mathematica* 11.1.1)

Comment: I'm very surprised both by wonderful efficiency of the `NotebookFind` + `NotebookDelete` approach and disappointing performance of the `Cells` + `NotebookDelete` approach...