# Delete all output in notebooks

Tags: notebooks, cells

I want to delete in all notebooks in a certain root directory all output cells as well as all other output generated during evaluation (e.g. from print and other) and afterwards save the cleaned notebooks using the same names.

From [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/how-to-select-and-delete-all-output-cells) (Yves Klett) I borrowed some code:

```
CleanNotebook[nb_: SelectedNotebook[], 
   styles_: {"Output"}] := (NotebookFind[nb, #, All, CellStyle];
     NotebookDelete[nb];) & /@ styles;

ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir], "Directory"], 
   Dynamic[imageDir]}];
notebookFiles = FileNames["*.nb", imageDir, Infinity];
num = Length[notebookFiles];

Do[
  file = notebookFiles[[i]];
  nb = NotebookOpen[file, Visible -> False];
  CleanNotebook[nb];
  NotebookSave[nb, file];
  NotebookClose[nb];
  , {i, 1, num}
  ];
```

My **problem**: Output cells seem to be correctly deleted BUT output from e.g. `Print` is not deleted. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Print` and `Message` and so on are generated cells, like the output from evaluating input. This, from the docs for `Cells`, is what you need (just substitute your actual notebook object for `EvaluationNotebook[]` in the code):

```
NotebookDelete[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True]]
```

[image]

I'd use `Map` instead of `Do` but in any case just replace `CleanNotebook[nb]` with `NotebookDelete[Cells[nb, GeneratedCell -> True]]` in your code.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Three additional alternatives:

1. Call `CleanNotebook` with two arguments in your `Do` loop:

```
CleanNotebook[nb, {"Output", "Print"}];
```

2. Replace the line  `CleanNotebook[nb];` in your `Do` loop with

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]];
```

3. Replace your `CleanNotebook` with

```
cleanNotebook[nb_: SelectedNotebook[]] := SetOptions[nb, NotebookEventActions -> 
 {"WindowClose" :>  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]}]
```