# Code to delete all output in a notebook

Tags: notebooks, cells, output

I am looking for a code I can paste at the beginning of a notebook to delete all the output cells so that when I execute the "Evaluate notebook" command, all the output cells are also cleared. As of now, I manually do "Cell > Delete All Output" before executing the "Evaluate notebook" command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16665](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166652/delete-all-output-in-notebooks), [13978](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/how-to-select-and-delete-all-output-cells) and perhaps several more.

Comment: FrontEndTokenExecute["DeleteGeneratedCells"]

Comment: @DanielHuber, thanks for your reply. I liked the command you suggested and will use it henceforth.