# Prepare notebook for students

Tags: notebooks

I'm preparing a notebook with some code for students to evaluate. I always check all the code myself while I make this notebook, and afterwards, I evaluate everything again to double-check. Of course, I don't want the evaluation results to be saved in the notebook. Neither do I want any extra data with regards to my evaluations stored as well. (I don't know what data is stored in a Notebook but it would be nice if only the input cells and layout were saved in it)

Is there an easy way to get rid of all

- output cells and
- possible side effects of evaluation

from a notebook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all output in notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166652/delete-all-output-in-notebooks) Also: [How to select and delete all Output cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/how-to-select-and-delete-all-output-cells)

Comment: Yes. It didn't come up when I searched for it though :/