# How to select and delete all Output cells within current Selection only?

Tags: front-end

A similar question was already here: [How to select and delete all Output cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/how-to-select-and-delete-all-output-cells). But I have a more specific one: I want to delete all output cells **within the currently selected cells** only.

For this purpose I want to add an additional menu item **Cell>Delete All Output within Selection**.

Probably one would have to add something to

`/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr`

**Has anybody already made such an improvement and could he please post it here?**

(The version in this case is 12.1 and it probably has to reflect the version in question. This path is for a Linux machine. On a Windows machine the paths begin at a different root but parts from `Wolfram` to `TextRessources` probably will look the same, except for the forward slashes being replaced by backward ones- `/X/` might be special for Linux).

Comment: If you select the cells you want to delete you simply need to click the delete key.

Comment: It seems like you could just save a version of your Notebook unevaluated in the input cells that interest you and then just reopen it when you don't want the designated output cells.

Comment: Daniel, your solution does not solve my problem, when I have a group of input cells which have their outputs grouped with them in my group of cells collectively executed. I want to get rid of all those output cells without having to select them one by one.

Comment: How about this: paste them to a new notebook, delete all output cells and them paste them back?

Comment: Creating a new menu item is not hard, but I think the solution described above may be also acceptable.