# How to stop the Kernel from running wild?

Tags: kernel

How to abort or stop this **(accidently large defined)** SparseArray production?

```
s = N[SparseArray[Table[{2^i, 4} -> i, {i, 30}]]]
```

Alt+. or Alt+, seem to give up. Even your Windows task manager is struggling.

Comment: `Evaluation->Quit Kernel -> Local` often succeeds where `Abort Evaluation` fails for me.

Comment: Related: [Do you really want to quit the kernel? Yes!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17357/do-you-really-want-to-quit-the-kernel-yes), [How to automate a FrontEnd return?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2003/89).

Comment: Concerning the Task Manager statement: Although the TM struggles, and can take a minute or two to respond, I find that patience pays off: navigate to the [Processes] tab, right-click on the instance of Mathkernel.exe that is hogging all the RAM, and choose "end process." Each step can require a painfully long wait, but in the end it does work.

Comment: Another related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2789/5

Answer (score 10):

Could use $Pre to wrap things in MemoryConstrained. I'll illustrate with an unusually tight constraint.

```
SetAttributes[memcon, HoldAll]
memcon[new_] := MemoryConstrained[new, 10^4]
$Pre = memcon;
```

Examples:

```
ByteCount[Range[10^6]]

(* Out[4]= $Aborted *)

s = N[SparseArray[Table[{2^i, 4} -> i, {i, 20}]]]

(* Out[5]= $Aborted *)
```

Comment: If you don't preclude the use of `$Pre` as I did in [my earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7854980/618728) this is an excellent method.  I recommend it to anyone using version 7 or earlier.  Belisarius gives a nice method for v8+ in the linked thread that does not tie up `$Pre`.

Comment: Another question would be: why does this fill up the memory at all?  The array is very sparse with only a few elements.  Is there a limit on the size of `SparseArray`s that's exceeded here?

Comment: @Szabolcs `InputForm[SparseArray[Table[{2^i, 4} -> i, {i, 5}]]]` seems to show a dense 1-d listwith the jth element indicating how many nontrivial elements have been seen prior to row j. That at least is my guess.