# How could I set TimeConstrained globally?

Tags: evaluation, kernel

I want to set `TimeConstrained` globally, I tried use `$PrePrint` as bellowed script:

```
$PrePrint = TimeConstrained[#,5] &;
```

But there's no effect, evaluation could not be aborted within given time.

So is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Consider `$Pre` and related items.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks a lot. I found the solution by searching '$Pre'.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution in another topic here

[How to stop the Kernel from running wild?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17714/how-to-stop-the-kernel-from-running-wild)

```
SetAttributes[timecon, HoldAll]
timecon[new_] := TimeConstrained[new, 5]
$Pre = timecon;
```