# Copy last/second last (etc.) input from history into current cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks, keyboard

I like to use terminals (e.g. `gnome-terminal`) where you can use the up key to copy the last command into the current input 'field'. For example, to repeat the last command you just have to press <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>. Or, to modify the last input and re-run, it is just <kbd>up</kbd>, modify, <kbd>enter</kbd>.

As beginner I often make mistakes, or experiment by slightly changing previous inputs. Is there any way in which I can obtain this convenient input behavior in the *Mathematica* front end?

Comment: You can always just go back and edit that cell.  Notebooks are not linear like a traditional command line.  You can edit any previous input without needing to "recall" it.  Perhaps you'll find this way of working more efficient if you get a bit used to it.

Comment: Have you seen edit to my answer? I am interested if it works with somebody else, because I didn't test it much.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried shortcuts like cmd+L and cmd+Shift+L ?
Perhaps these can be even overridden and generalized for next to last Input/Output cells and above. But, I'm still not sure how to do it.

### Edit

Ok, so I managed to do it. (It took me almost two days, but I was inspired..)

To modify keyboard shortcuts or add new, it's necessary to change `KeyEventTranslations.tr` and/or `MenuSetup.tr` located in

`$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/$OperatingSystem/`

There are already several good ideas for making user defined keyboard shortcuts or menu items ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/907/how-do-i-add-new-menuitems-to-menus), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/delete-the-current-notebook-cell-using-the-keyboard), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting), [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6224/best-way-to-add-keyevents-and-faster-quit/6227#6227), [5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-to-automate-a-frontend-return)...), which can really save you some time at work once you adjust them as it suits.
**As these are system files, make sure to make a back-up before editing them.** When/If you get more familiar with adding new shortcuts, you may also consider automating this procedure as shown [here](http://www.mertig.com/shortcuts.m) by Rolf Mertig.

For listing previous inputs in the selected notebook, in their original input form (***what you asked***), I made two new shortcuts and pasted them using **text editor** in `KeyEventTranslations.tr` right **after** the line `EventTranslations[{`

```
(*
Command Up   -   creates Terminal cell in which user can list previous inputs upwards to oldest
*)
Item[KeyEvent["Up", Modifiers -> {Command}], 
KernelExecute[With[{nb = SelectedNotebook[]},
 If[And[ValueQ[$TraceLine], NotebookFind[nb, "Terminal", Next, CellLabel] =!= $Failed],
  If[$TraceLine > 1,
    $TraceLine = $TraceLine - 1;
    SelectionMove[nb, All, CellContents];
    NotebookWrite[nb,
     ReplaceAll[ToBoxes[ReplaceAll[ReplaceAll[Hold[In[n] // InputForm], n -> $TraceLine], DownValues[In]]], RowBox[{"Hold", "[", Longest[Pattern[x,BlankSequence[]]], "]"}] -> x]
   ]
   , Beep[]
  ]
  , If[$Line > 1,
    $TraceLine = $Line - 1;
    SelectionMove[nb, After, CellGroup, 2];
    NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[
     BoxData[ReplaceAll[ToBoxes[ReplaceAll[ReplaceAll[Hold[In[n] // InputForm], n -> $TraceLine], DownValues[In]]], RowBox[{"Hold", "[", Longest[Pattern[x,BlankSequence[]]], "]"}] -> x]],
    "Input", CellLabel -> "Terminal", CellLabelAutoDelete -> False, ShowCursorTracker -> False
   ]];
   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["MovePrevious"]]
   , Beep[]
  ]
 ]
]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
],
(*
Command Down   -   lists down previous inputs in Terminal cell down do most recent
*)
Item[KeyEvent["Down", Modifiers -> {Command}], 
KernelExecute[With[{nb = SelectedNotebook[]},
 If[And[ValueQ[$TraceLine], NotebookFind[nb, "Terminal", Next, CellLabel] =!= $Failed, $TraceLine < $Line - 1],
  $TraceLine = $TraceLine + 1;
  SelectionMove[nb, All, CellContents];
  NotebookWrite[nb,
   ReplaceAll[ToBoxes[ReplaceAll[ReplaceAll[Hold[In[n] // InputForm], n -> $TraceLine], DownValues[In]]], RowBox[{"Hold", "[", Longest[Pattern[x,BlankSequence[]]], "]"}] -> x]
  ]
  , Beep[]
 ]
]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
],
```

Abilities:

- I've chosen ⌘↑ and ⌘↓, but one can as well set different in element `KeyEvent[]`, where Modifiers can be "Shift", "Control", "Command", "Option"

  - For Macintosh: "Command" = Command Key, "Option" = Option Key
  - For Windows: "Command" = Alt, "Option" = Alt
- When choosing key shortcut, be sure that there are no overlaps afterwards. For example, I have deleted original shortcuts for ⌘↑ and ⌘↓, from the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, before using them! But you can find some other or override original ⌘L
- This routine uses global variable `$Line` and function `In[]`. Therefore functionality depends on setting `$HistoryLength` (through `In[]`). The routine also creates one global variable `$TraceLine`, which is unprotected as well as `$Line`
- When pressing first time the shortcut key it creates a new cell close to current position of the cursor with a label "Terminal", where previous inputs are being listed (with a possibility for the change). After evaluation of the cell it will change its label to "In[$Line]:=" as all other input cells.
- Before evaluating the cell "Terminal" user can go around and change, evaluate other cells and then continue listing inputs where he/she stopped, but **only** at the same "Terminal" cell - more than one will not be created, instead it will move your cursor automatically to that cell.

Any suggestions for improvements or simplifications are welcome.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking for exactly this behavior. However, the code doesn't seem to be working on Windows. I gather that I *don't* need to find/replace "Command" with "Alt", correct? Using it as-is, should result in the key-bindings being set for alt+up and alt+down. I also didn't see any bindings with `["Up/Down", Modifiers->{Command}]` in the file to delete.

Comment: Hmm, seems the `alt` modifier is being globally used or overwritten to give focus to the menu bar. The script works when I changed the modifier to `shift`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using [`InString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InString), [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler) and [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule).

1. [`InString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InString) is used to retrieve the box structure for the input cells in the history.
2. [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler) is used to capture the keys <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, and <kbd>esc</kbd>.
3. [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule) is used to create the dynamic interface.

Here's the code:

```
ViewInputs[Unevaluated[line_:$Line]] := With[
    {
    cellMargins = Replace[
        CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", CellMargins}],
        {{a_, _}, {_, _}} -> {{a, 0}, {0, 0}}
    ]
    },

    DynamicModule[{k = line},
        NotebookWrite[
            EvaluationCell[],
            Cell[
                BoxData @ TagBox[
                    DynamicBox[ToExpression@InString[k]],
                    EventHandlerTag[
                        {
                        "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (k=Mod[k-1, $Line-1, 1]),
                    "DownArrowKeyDown" :>(k=Mod[k+1, $Line-1, 1]),
                        {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> NotebookWrite[
                            EvaluationCell[],
                            ToExpression[InString[k]]
                        ],
                        "ReturnKeyDown" :> NotebookWrite[
                            EvaluationCell[],
                            ToExpression[InString[k]]
                        ],
                        "EscapeKeyDown" :> (
                            NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]];
                            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, Cell]
                        ),
                        PassEventsDown->False
                        }
                    ],
                    Selectable->False
                ],
                "Input",
                Evaluatable->False,
                CellLabel->"↑: Up    ↓: Down    \[EnterKey]: Use    \[EscapeKey]: Cancel",
                CellLabelMargins -> cellMargins,
                CellLabelPositioning->Above,
                CellLabelStyle->Directive["CellLabel", FontSize->10],
                CellFrame -> {{False,False}, {False,True}},
                CellDingbat -> Cell[
                    BoxData @ TemplateBox[
                        {"\"In[\"", DynamicBox[ToBoxes@k], "\"]:=\""},
                        "RowDefault"
                    ],
                    "CellLabel",
                    FontFamily->"Helvetica",
                    FontWeight->"Plain",
                    ShowStringCharacters->False
                ]
            ]
        ];
        SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, CellContents];
    ];
]
```

Using the up and down arrows cycles through the input history. Using enter or shift+enter replaces the interface with the input. Finally, using the escape key cancels the interface. Here's an animation showing the interface in action:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One easy thing to do is to get used to naming your cells. Start your cell with

```
 x1 = (cell contents)
```

then you can later go back and it already has a name. Alternatively, you can refer to cells by their number;

```
 In[27]
```

is the 27th cell defined in this session.

Comment: If I write `5!` in cell 10, then In[10] evaluates to 120. Ideally, I need to be able to press something (e.g.<up>) during input mode in cell 11 that makes content of In[11] sames as In[10] (while still possible to edit it)

Comment: There is also Control-L (Apple-L) that will copy down the input cell above your insertion point.

Comment: Thank so much for this! (any idea if something works for depth more than 1?)