# undisputed FrontEndTokenExecute

Tags: front-end

Thanks to [this great topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-front-end-tokens), I've found the `FrontEndToken` that I was looking for:
`"DeleteGeneratedCells"` (well, it is also written in `Help` but I've found it later :)

**Question:**
I would love to execute it in `NotebookObject` without confirmation through the automatically displayed `ChoiceDialog["Do You really want to..."]`.

Is it maybe a case of `FrontEndTokenExecute` **parameters**?

I suspect I can deal with it by setting some global options for *Mathematica* but I would rather leave them.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [How to automate a FrontEnd return?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2003/89)

Comment: @IstvánZachar I would say it is very closely related because our purposes are a bit little different and acceptable solutions too. But we will see what community decides ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this. Make a list of the generated cells like this:

```
cells = Cells[GeneratedCell -> True];
```

Then delete them from the notebook using this

```
NotebookDelete[cells];
```

Comment: I had to check but it seems that for my needs this works well. And there is no `ChoiceDialog[]` so thank You for this answer :)

Comment: @Kuba no problem, glad you like it :)

Comment: I'm very happy to see answers using the under-utilized `Cells` function.  But I'm not sure what you mean by your statement that this "doesn't use the front end".  Both `Cells` and `NotebookDelete` require a front end to work properly, and they're implemented by causing the kernel to issue commands to the front end.  Incidentally, code very similar to this is in the Applications Examples section of the `Cells` documentation.

Comment: @JohnFultz ah, yes, I have made this mistake in another Q&A as well, and fortunately there I was immediately corrected. I should have remembered this Q&A. Thank you