# Automatically close Mathematica

Tags: front-end, notebooks

It seems there are a lot of related topics but I haven't found an answer.

I want to automatically quit *Mathematica* after some procedures are done but dialog window appears:

```
1 + 1;
NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[]];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FrontEndQuit"]]
```

[image]

One can put this inside `Button`

```
Button["close",
        1 + 1; NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[]];
        FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FrontEndQuit"]]
      ]
```

what will work but I need it works as a part of procedure because the notebook is called automatically and no one is going to click OK.

This Q&A is almost a duplicate of
[undisputed FrontEndTokenExecute](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25585/5478) but there was the work around.

**I appreciate a work around but also the general question, how to stop or automatically agree with `Dialogs` is what I'm interested in.**

Maybe it's relevant: Win XP/Win 7 *Mathematica* V9.0.0.1

Comment: @Anon but **when** to close? :) It is called via `WindowsTaskManager` but I can switch to cmd if you show me how to catch some mark from MMA that will tell cdm to close it.

Comment: By the way, isn't it strange that it offers to put the result to the MessageWindow since I'm closing MMA?:)

Comment: Hah, I deleted my comment in like two seconds didn't think you'd see it... I realized it might not be viable for you. But what I meant was to save your notebook content into an .m file and execute it via command line. I didn't think there was reason to open a notebook in the first place if noone was there to see it.

Comment: When I want to automatically close _Mathematica_, I do `ListPlot3D[bigdata]` and try to rotate the view :D :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a separate FE token that can do this.

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuitNonInteractive"]
```

Comment: Ahh, it's also [on complete list there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2582/5478), thank you. Do you maybe know the answer for general question, about preventing `Dialogs`? The answer that we can't do anything is also information :)

Comment: @Kuba, if you run the front end with the `-server` command-line option, then it will not prompt dialog boxes.  But it will also not be usable by the user.  This is, for example, how the kernel command `UsingFrontEnd` launches the kernel.  Since you don't provide very much context for your question, it's not clear to me whether this is a useful answer to your question.

Comment: I was thinking about something like `Check` but detecting dialogs. Also with functionality to automatically agree or not with them. I do know if it is possible, just asking.

Comment: @Kuba it's not possible to do anything like what you're asking for globally for arbitrary Mathematica commands.  If you're sticking to fully documented Mathematica functions, you shouldn't ever see interactive prompts unless that's the purpose of the function (e.g., `Input`).  But many of the FE tokens were implemented only for the purpose of user interaction through the menu system, and do not represent the gold standard of end-to-end design that we generally apply to fully documented functions.

Comment: Thank you, I think it exhausts the topic. :)

Answer (score 9):

As a workaround, try this:

```
1 + 1;
NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[]];
RunScheduledTask[FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FrontEndQuit"]]];
```

This will only work if the kernel evaluations have actually finished, you can't use it half-way through a calculation.

Comment: Thank you, it works for my purposes. Can you explain why this is considered by Mathematica different evaluation or something?

Comment: @Kuba, the message in the dialog says that a **notebook** contains a running evaluation. As I understand it, scheduled tasks are not associated with any specific notebook, so there is no reason for the front end to complain.

Comment: Why not close all Untitled notebooks also? : 
`RunScheduledTask[
  Map[NotebookClose, 
           Select[
             Notebooks[], FreeQ[
                NotebookInformation[#], "FileName"] & ]];
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FrontEndQuit"]]];
               NotebookInformation[#], "FileName"] & ]];`