# How to close all windows or just quit mathematica from code?

Tags: front-end

So my problem is that I want to be able to close all of my currently open windows/notebooks from my code, but `Quit[]` only quits the current kernel. Is there any command to do this besides `NotebookClose[]`, which requires that I pass in the notebook to close which I won't necessarily have available?

Thanks!

P.S. If you need me to clarify, just say so!

Comment: `NotebookClose /@ Notebooks[]` but if there is something to save you don't care about, use: [`FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuitNonInteractive"]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30974/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows:

```
Run["taskkill /F /FI \"IMAGENAME eq Mathematica.exe\" > nul"]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!! The only problem is that I use a Mac, but thanks for making me aware of Run[]!